# DOMDocument issue replacing paragraphs elements

Tags: php, laravel

in my laravel app I want to use DOMDocument to replace node values of each paragraph element by new values, for this I'm looping through each p element and replacing it with a new element, however I'm getting the following error:

```
Not Found Error, DOMException
```

On this line:

```
$dom->replaceChild($newNode, $pnode);
```

My method:

```
$htmlString = 
        '<section>
        <h2>Introducción</h2>
        <p>Primer acto</p>
        <p>Segundo acto</p>
        <p>Tercer acto</p>
        <p>Climax</p>
        <p>A volar</p>
        </section>';

        
        $dom = new \DOMDocument();
        libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
        $dom->loadHTML($htmlString);

        foreach( $dom->getElementsByTagName("p") as $pnode ) 
        {
            $result = 'New Translated Value';

            $newNode = $dom->createElement("p", $result);
            $dom->replaceChild($newNode, $pnode);

            usleep( 500000 );
        }
        $dom->saveHTML($dom);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: shouldn't  `replaceChild` be called on the parent element that contains the element you want to replace? ... also why not just replace the content of the element?

Answer (score 0):

The error message "Not Found Error, DOMException" on the line `$dom->replaceChild($newNode, $pnode);` means that the $pnode element is not found in the current DOM document, for this reason the replaceChild() method cannot replace it with the new element $newNode.

This error may occur if the getElementsByTagName() method does not return any

elements in the DOM document. To check if this is the case, you can add a simple if statement to verify that the $pnode variable is not null before attempting to replace it with a new node.

This is the new code with the check added:

```
$htmlString = 
    '<section>
        <h2>Introducción</h2>
        <p>Primer acto</p>
        <p>Segundo acto</p>
        <p>Tercer acto</p>
        <p>Climax</p>
        <p>A volar</p>
    </section>';

$dom = new \DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($htmlString);

foreach( $dom->getElementsByTagName("p") as $pnode ) 
{
    $result = 'New Translated Value';

    $newNode = $dom->createElement("p", $result);
    
    // check if $pnode exists before replacing it
    if ($pnode) {
        $dom->replaceChild($newNode, $pnode);
    }
    
    usleep(500000);
}

// print the updated HTML
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

This should work!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`$pnode->replaceWith()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domchildnode.replacewith.php) to replace the node with other nodes.

```php
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName("p") as $pnode) {
    /** @var DOMElement $pnode */
    $result = 'New Translated Value';

    $newNode = $dom->createElement("p", $result);

    $pnode->replaceWith($newNode);
}
```